# Why can't I open my custom file extension from the Downloads application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-file

I'm able to open my app's custom file extension from Gmail or from file explorer, but I'm not able to open it from the built-in Downloads application (which is apparently where Yahoo Mail puts attachments). Why is this and how do I fix it?

My main activity's intent filters:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.grdcsv" android:mimeType="*/*" android:host="*"/>  
</intent-filter>
<!-- For email attachments -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.grdcsv" android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It is the Downloads app that does not know how to behave. Other file extensions go wrong too. Download a .pdf and try to open it and you will see.

Comment: I just tried this and PDFs open just fine. It prompts me to select which app to use.

Comment: Mmmm.. then sorry for the confusion. Why does it hit me then?